# WordPress Custom Sub Menu, Custom Sizing Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm having some difficulty figuring this one out. I'm trying to customize my nav bar in Wordpress so that when I hover over the Sub-menu, the Sub-Sub menu starts at the top, regardless of which Sub-menu I'm hovering over.

Amazon's menu structure is a great example of what I am looking to do. Regardless of what department you hover your mouse over, the menu size stays the same and starts from the top.

My nav menu structure right now is:

Main Nav

- Sub-menu1
- Sub-menu2
- Sub-menu3
- Sub-menu4
- Sub-menu5

Right now, when I hover over Sub-menu 1, the next menu will open parallel to Sub-menu 1 (Good). When I hover over Sub-menu 2, the next menu will open parallel to Sub-menu 2 (Bad). I want it to open at the same height as the sub-menu 1 line, regardless of whether I'm hovering over Sub-menu 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. I also want to keep the sub-sub menu the same size, regardless of how many links I'll be putting in there.

Can someone please assist?

```
/**
 * 4.2 Navigation
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: url("images/saprator.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
}

.nav-menu li ul li { background:none;}
.nav-menu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 12px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Ubuntu',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    XXXtext-transform:uppercase;    
}

.nav-menu li a:hover{ color:#FFFFFF;}
.nav-menu li:last-child { background:none;}

.nav-menu .sub-menu,
.nav-menu .children {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
    padding: 6px;
    background:url("images/dropdown_bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent ;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    padding: 5px;

}

.nav-menu li li a,
.nav-menu .sub-menu a, .nav-menu .children a{ 


    XXborder-radius: 3px;
    XX-moz-border-radius: 3px;
    XX-khtml-border-radius: 3px;


    color: #777777;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-transform: capitalize; 
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover, .nav-menu .children a:hover{ 
    color: #903537;
}






.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
.nav-menu .children ul {
    left:160px;
    top:0px;
}
.nav-menu li.main-li:nth-last-child(1) .sub-menu ul, 
.nav-menu li.main-li:nth-last-child(1) .children ul,
.nav-menu li.main-li:nth-last-child(2) .sub-menu ul, 
.nav-menu li.main-li:nth-last-child(2) .children ul,
.nav-menu li.main-li:nth-last-child(3) .sub-menu ul, 
.nav-menu li.main-li:nth-last-child(3) .children ul {
    left: -200px;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
    width: 205px;
}
ul.nav-menu ul a,
.nav-menu ul ul a {
    margin: 0;
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a:hover,
.nav-menu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.nav-menu .current_page_item > a,
.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a { }
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

/* Navbar */

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    background: url("images/menu_bg.png") repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    position:relative;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-form, #searchform {
    background: url("images/search_bg.png") repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;  
    text-align: right;
    width: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}
.header-main .search-form, 
.header-main #searchform {
     position: absolute;
     top: 45px;
    left: 0;
}
.search-field, 
#searchform input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #E8E6DD;
    cursor: text;
    outline: 0;
    width: 235px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding:5px 30px 5px 8px;
    float:left;

}
.widget-area .search-form, 
.widget-area #searchform{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    width: 100%;
}



input[type=text]{

border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;

}




.header-main .search-field:focus, 
.header-main #searchform input[type="text"]:focus {}
.search-field:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus { border: 1px solid #E8E6DD; border: 1px solid #d1d3d4; }
.search-form .search-submit, #searchform #searchsubmit {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0px -222px transparent !important;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-indent: -959px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 24px;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 1px;
}
.search-form .search-submit:hover, 
.search-form .search-submit:focus,
#searchform #searchsubmit:hover, 
#searchform #searchsubmit:focus{ background: none; border: none;}
.widget-area .search-form .search-submit,
.widget-area #searchform #searchsubmit{ top: -5px;}
#tertiary .sidebar-inner .search-field,
#tertiary .sidebar-inner input[type="text"] { margin-top:0; width: 100%;}
.widget_search{ overflow: hidden; position:relative;}
.header-login-logout{ 
}

/*** Top Area ***/

#top-area{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
}

/*** End Top Area ***/

#menu-navigation-bar menu, #menu-navigation-bar ol, #menu-navigation-bar ul  {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #FFF;

}




#menu-navigation-bar .position1 span, #menu-navigation-bar .position2 span, #menu-navigation-bar .position3 span{
    display: block;
    color: #243889 !important;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #FFF;

}



        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li {
            height: auto;

            line-height: 16px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            float: none;
            background-color: #FFF;
            XXcolor: #000000 !important;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: none;
            position: relative;


        }   


            #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li.wide:hover {
                XXbackground: #ecf0f1;
                XXbackground-color: #ecf0f1 !important;

                    -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .2s;
                -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .2s;

            }





        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li.wide { 
            //width: 720px; 
            XXbackground-color: #ecf0f1; 
            overflow: auto; 

            position: relative;
            left: 2px;
            border: 0px solid #dde4e6; 

        }




        /* widths for the slide-menu based on how many panels (positions)  are loaded  */
        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li.position-1 { width: 200px; }
        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li.position-2 { width: 400px; }
        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li.position-3 { width: 600px; }
        /* panel positions */
        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li div.position1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 600px;
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li div.position2 {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
            #menu-navigation-bar ul.slide-menu li div.position3 {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            }       
        /* styles */
        #menu-navigation-bar ul li.end ul.sub-menu li ul.slide-menu li.wide div { 
            font-family: open sans, arial; 
            font-weight: bold; 

}


        #menu-navigation-bar ul li.end ul.sub-menu li ul.slide-menu li.wide div ul.mini li {
            padding: 2px;
            margin: 3px;
            list-style-type: none;
            list-style-position: inside;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #333333;

        }

        #menu-navigation-bar ul li.end ul.sub-menu li ul.slide-menu li.wide div ul.mini li a {
            color: #333333;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Open Sans, Arial;

                    }

        #menu-navigation-bar ul li.end ul.sub-menu li ul.slide-menu li.wide div ul.mini li:hover {
            font-color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Open Sans, Arial;
            XXbackground-color: #fff !important;
            transition: ease-in-out all .2s; 
                -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .2s;
            -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .2s;

        }









        .sub-menu{
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CCCCCC;

            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;



        }



        #menu-navigation-bar{
            XXXbox-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CCCCCC;

            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

        }



        .slide-menu{

            padding-left: 10px !important;
            padding-bottom: 10px !important;

        }





        .slide-menu a{

            font-size: 14px !important;
            padding: 0px !important;
            padding-left: 10px !important;
            padding-top: 5px !important;
        }



.subHeader{

    font-size: 19px !important;
}




    .gridNav{

        margin-bottom: 16px;
        margin-left: 11px;
    }


    .gridNav td{
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .gridNav td:nth-child(3){
        font-size: 12px;

    }

    .gridNav:first-child, .gridButton, #catfilters a, #searchwithin{
        padding-left: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #E0E0E0;



        background: rgb(255,255,255);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,237,237,1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );



    }
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code to have any chance of debugging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Or are you asking for someone to write it for you?
Here is how you would begin:

```
ul.nav-menu{display:block;}
ul.nav-menu > ul{
    display:block;
    left:200px;
}
```

Comment: I've added the css. I'm having trouble locating which line of code will make the menu do what I want it to do. @BenRacicot

Comment: You're new to CSS? You'll want to look for the most Parent container. In this case the <ul>. It looks like nav-menu > ul is targetting your sub menu